# Unable to pass multiple values from one screen to the multiple textview boxes of the another screen in android

Tags: android, web-services, textview

I am trying to consume a web service from android by the method SOAP.
Here my problem is,actually i am getting two values from that web service namely "OrderNo" and "FreightRate" and i am trying to show these values in each Text-view boxes of the next screen but i am getting nothing on the text view boxes,

How to achieve this concept?Suggestions please..

**NOTE :-**  **I can able to show only any one values in the text view box of the another screen if i consume any one values like "orderNo" or "FreightRate". But unable to show two values simultaneously in separate text-view boxes of the another screen.**

*Please find my sources for reference*

**Main_WB.java**

```
 public class Main_WB extends Activity 
 {
EditText edt1,edt2;
//TextView txt_1;

Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(),edt2.getText().toString());
    //  Intent myint = new Intent(Main_WB.this,ResultActivity.class);
    //  startActivity(myint);
    }     
    });
 }

 private void getTMSChart(String FromDate,String ToDate)
 {
// txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

 System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        

 envelope.dotNet = true;

 String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
 String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);        
 request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);               
 request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

 try 
 {
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
    {
       SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
       int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

    //   String[] ord = new String[propertyCount];
    //   String[] fre = new String[propertyCount];

    // int[] fre = new int[propertyCount];
    // int[] margin = new int[propertyCount];

    for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
    {   

    String x,y;

    // int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
    // int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
    // int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));

    String orderNo =  table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No");
    String freight = table.getAttributeAsString("Freight_Rate");


    x = orderNo.toString();
    y = freight.toString();
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("gotonextpage",x);
    in.putExtra("gotonextpage", y);
    startActivity(in);




    //ord[j] = orderNo;
    //  fre[j] = freightRate;
    // margin[j]= marginPercent;

    //   x = orderNo.toString();
    //   y = fre.toString();

    //   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main_WB.this, ResultActivity.class);
    //   myIntent.putExtra("gotonextpage", x);
    //   startActivity(myIntent);


    // whatever you do with these values
          }                   
       }
    }   
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }   
 } }
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
 public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
 {
String x,y;
TextView txt1,txt2;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   
    x = extras.getString("gotonextpage");
    y = extras.getString("gotonextpage");
}
else
{   
}
txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw);
txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw2);
txt1.setText(x);
txt2.setText(y);


}}
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not your problem but, in your main activity you're trying to send both values with your intent but you are adding them using the same key. In your example you are always sending value y because you're overwriting the x value.

```
in.putExtra("gotonextpage",x);
in.putExtra("gotonextpage", y);
```

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use two different keys for your values, when sending them with the intent, and extracting them.

```
in.putExtra("gotonextpageX",x);
in.putExtra("gotonextpageY", y);

x = extras.getString("gotonextpageX");
y = extras.getString("gotonextpageY");
```

Another way to do it is

```
x = getIntent().getStringExtra("gotonextpageX");
y = getIntent().getStringExtra("gotonextpageY");
```